# Java 2d char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

Good day everyone, for the past couple of days I have been working on converting a 1D string array to a 2D char array. My 1D array works fine(zero issues) but when I convert to the 2D char array it only prints out the first row. Below is my code. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) //prints out array
{  
    System.out.println("1d " + number[i]); //prints the line from the file
}
final int ROWS = 7;
final int COLS = 5;

char[][] 2darray = new char [ROWS][COLS];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    2darray[i]= array1[i].toCharArray();   
}

for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
    {
         System.out.print(2darray[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You seem to have 3 arrays.

Comment: This will not compile; variable names can't start with a number.

Comment: And in two instances you have `array.length`, but this should be `array1.length()-1`  Also, you need to have `row < ROWS-1` and `col < COLS-1`.  Does this compile?  Does this execute without error?

Comment: As of now, it does compile

Comment: You said it outputs the first char-array, but not the rest.  Does it crash?  Or just nothing happens?

Comment: @user2817804 What's happened with your earlier question? [1DStringTo2DChar](https://gist.github.com/TheKojuEffect/6715379) didn't help?

Comment: What I don't understand is the inconsistent use of final ints to determine the size of your array, and using length to loop (some) arrays

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have variables start with a number in Java. I suggest changing your variables accordingly and trying it out.

```
char[][] array2 = new char [ROWS][COLS];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
{
    array2[i]= array1[i].toCharArray();   
}

for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
    {
         System.out.print(array2[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This still has errors (not yours, his).  `array.length` should instead be `array1.length()-1`, `row < ROWS` should be `row < ROWS-1`, and same for `col < COLS` should be `col < COLS-1`

Comment: @nhgrif `array1.length()` doesn't compile

Comment: What is his string array called?  I thought his string array was array1?

Comment: The problem is that it is only printing the first row, its printing out blank rows after the first

Comment: @nhgrif arrays don't have a method `length()`, they have a final field `length`

Comment: Oh, got it.  Okay, confusing my languages.  Does `.length` return the number of indexes, or the value of the largest index?  Either way, I think the core problem with the original question is his for loops are going out of bounds.

Comment: @nhgrif `length` is the number of indices, so I don't think you need to use `length-1`, so long as you're using `<` and not `<=`

Comment: Got it.  Still need `ROWS-1` and `COLS-1` though.

Answer (score 1):

**See Comments**

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) //prints out array
{  
    // Why did you use number ?
    System.out.println("1d " + array1[i]); //prints the line from the file
}

// You don't need these now.
// final int ROWS = 7;
//  final int COLS = 5;


// This will initialize 2darray of size as required according to length of array1
char[][] 2darray = new char [array1.length][];

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) // What is `array`?
{
    2darray[i]= array1[i].toCharArray();   
}

for (int row = 0; row < 2darray.length; row++) // Use actual size of 2darray row
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 2darray[i].length; col++) // use actual size of 2darray column
    { 
         System.out.print(2darray[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```